# Automate Drupal Reindex

Tags: drush

I wrote a ruby script to create a "Help" doc installation on a test machine (CentOS, VM).
On step of the process is to reindex the data for the "Help" doc installation (5GB of data).
The total amount of data to reindex is: (according to drupal search-status)
    1438 items

When running the reindex cron job manually:
    drush -v cron
I need to rerun cron a few times since not all data is being reindexed at one cron run. But in the end all data is being reindexed.

In the automation script I execute the shell command:
    session.exec!(drush -v cron)
and via the onetime login I can manually verify that data is being indexed.
However, after the shell command has been executed a few times, the cron job just hangs and does not pick up again. I even tried to run the drupal command manually, but it seemed that drupal was just horked. I actually needed to reboot my test machine to complete the reindexing.

Would it be better to run the shell command:
    drush -v search-reindex
to force a reindex and not even rely on the cron job to do the reindexing.